# How to best replace global variables in Joomla extensions

Tags: php, joomla, superglobals

The Joomla Extensions Directory puts pressure on developers not to use global variables (superglobals) such as `$_SERVER, $_REQUEST, $_POST, $_GET, $_FILES, $_ENV, $_COOKIE, and $_SESSION` to prevent SQL injections.

I'm mostly concerned about the `$_GET` variable which is widely used in my extension. What's the best way of replacing `$_GET` without having to make too many changes to the application?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52526027/2943403 , https://stackoverflow.com/q/45152415/2943403 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/45123677/2943403

Answer (score 0):

The `JApplication` Object has a property `input` which holds all $_POST and $_GET  Data for you. It works something like that:

```
$jinput = $JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$data = $jinput->get('getparamter');
```

There is plenty of documentation out there for for the use of that input object. [Here is the API Documentation](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/Joomla.CMS.Input.Input.html)

$_SERVER, $_SESSION and others are replaces with userState and similar mechanisms, there really is no need to use of superglobals in Joomla.